# svg animate paths using animate tag to show loading dots

Tags: html, svg

I am unable to get the svg dots (paths) to animate using the fill property

```html
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first SVG</h1>

<svg width="100" height="100">
    <g id="Group-3" transform="translate(18.000000, 43.000000)">
                <path fill="#E1F1F6" d="M1.99995389,4 C1.18943703,3.99996826 0.459080007,3.51075355 0.150588108,2.76124016 C-0.157903792,2.01172677 0.0164743319,1.15013249 0.592137819,0.579563372 C1.16780131,0.00899425181 2.03091154,-0.157718518 2.77765322,0.157423404 C3.52439491,0.472565326 4.00709836,1.20724199 3.99992565,2.01772711 C3.99021168,3.11536294 3.09763271,4.00004298 1.99995389,4 L1.99995389,4 Z" id="Path" >
                  <animate id="first" attributeName="fill" from="#89CBDF" to="#E1F1F6" begin="1s;first.end+3s" dur="1s"/>
                </path>
                <path fill="#89CBDF" d="M9.99995389,4 C9.18943703,3.99996826 8.45908001,3.51075355 8.15058811,2.76124016 C7.84209621,2.01172677 8.01647433,1.15013249 8.59213782,0.579563372 C9.16780131,0.00899425181 10.0309115,-0.157718518 10.7776532,0.157423404 C11.5243949,0.472565326 12.0070984,1.20724199 11.9999256,2.01772711 C11.9902117,3.11536294 11.0976327,4.00004298 9.99995389,4 L9.99995389,4 Z" id="Path" >
                  <animate id="second" attributeName="fill" from="#89CBDF" to="#E1F1F6" begin="2s;second.end+3s" dur="1s"/>
                </path>
                <path fill="#89CBDF" d="M17.9999539,4 C17.189437,3.99996826 16.45908,3.51075355 16.1505881,2.76124016 C15.8420962,2.01172677 16.0164743,1.15013249 16.5921378,0.579563372 C17.1678013,0.00899425181 18.0309115,-0.157718518 18.7776532,0.157423404 C19.5243949,0.472565326 20.0070984,1.20724199 19.9999256,2.01772711 C19.9902117,3.11536294 19.0976327,4.00004298 17.9999539,4 L17.9999539,4 Z" id="Path" >
                  <animate id="third" attributeName="fill" from="#89CBDF" to="#E1F1F6" begin="3s;third.end+3s" dur="1s" />
                </path>
            </g>
</svg> 

</body>
</html>
```

My expectation is that the first dot will animate in 1 second and last for 1 seconds and then the second dot will begin (highlight and fade itself) and then the third but this will go on forever.

Any pointers on sequencing this would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be  missing fill="freeze" on the animation to keep it in the final animated state post animation e.g.

```html
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first SVG</h1>

<svg width="100" height="100">
    <g id="Group-3" transform="translate(18.000000, 43.000000)">
                <path fill="#E1F1F6" d="M1.99995389,4 C1.18943703,3.99996826 0.459080007,3.51075355 0.150588108,2.76124016 C-0.157903792,2.01172677 0.0164743319,1.15013249 0.592137819,0.579563372 C1.16780131,0.00899425181 2.03091154,-0.157718518 2.77765322,0.157423404 C3.52439491,0.472565326 4.00709836,1.20724199 3.99992565,2.01772711 C3.99021168,3.11536294 3.09763271,4.00004298 1.99995389,4 L1.99995389,4 Z" id="Path" >
                  <animate id="first" attributeName="fill" from="#89CBDF" to="#E1F1F6" begin="1s;first.end+3s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
                </path>
                <path fill="#89CBDF" d="M9.99995389,4 C9.18943703,3.99996826 8.45908001,3.51075355 8.15058811,2.76124016 C7.84209621,2.01172677 8.01647433,1.15013249 8.59213782,0.579563372 C9.16780131,0.00899425181 10.0309115,-0.157718518 10.7776532,0.157423404 C11.5243949,0.472565326 12.0070984,1.20724199 11.9999256,2.01772711 C11.9902117,3.11536294 11.0976327,4.00004298 9.99995389,4 L9.99995389,4 Z" id="Path" >
                  <animate id="second" attributeName="fill" from="#89CBDF" to="#E1F1F6" begin="2s;second.end+3s" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
                </path>
                <path fill="#89CBDF" d="M17.9999539,4 C17.189437,3.99996826 16.45908,3.51075355 16.1505881,2.76124016 C15.8420962,2.01172677 16.0164743,1.15013249 16.5921378,0.579563372 C17.1678013,0.00899425181 18.0309115,-0.157718518 18.7776532,0.157423404 C19.5243949,0.472565326 20.0070984,1.20724199 19.9999256,2.01772711 C19.9902117,3.11536294 19.0976327,4.00004298 17.9999539,4 L17.9999539,4 Z" id="Path" >
                  <animate id="third" attributeName="fill" from="#89CBDF" to="#E1F1F6" begin="3s;third.end+3s" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
                </path>
            </g>
</svg> 

</body>
</html>
```